# Ionic 2 RC0 And Angular 2 latest Error on Build android (ngc: Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically)

Tags: android, angular, typescript, compilation, ionic2

Error Appear when i build android using `ionic build android` command

ngc: Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'dictionary'. Consider exporting the symbol (position 14:8 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol TRANSLATION_PROVIDERS

My code in translation.ts file

```
export const TRANSLATIONS = new OpaqueToken('translations');
// all traslations
 const dictionary : any = {
    [LANG_EN_NAME]: LANG_EN_TRANS,
    [LANG_AR_NAME]: LANG_AR_TRANS,
    [LANG_FR_NAME]: LANG_FR_TRANS
};
// providers
export const TRANSLATION_PROVIDERS : any = [
    { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: dictionary},
];
```

My app.module.ts code

```
import {TRANSLATION_PROVIDERS,TranslatePipe,TranslateService} from './translate';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,

  ],
  providers: [TRANSLATION_PROVIDERS,TranslateService ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

any suggestions about this issue, by the way when im using `ionic serve` command  my project work 100% with transaltion

Comment: Can you create a minimum git repo?

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround for that.

you don't have to export your dictionary object, just change the keys to static values.

This worked for me:

```
// all translations
const dictionary = {
  "en": LANG_EN_TRANS,
  "ar": LANG_AR_TRANS,
  "fr": LANG_FR_TRANS
};
// providers
export const TRANSLATION_PROVIDERS = [
  { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: dictionary },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes exactly as said by @welefish in his answer, no need to export your dictionary object, you just have to change to keys to static value.

PS:- another method (Posting as answer because @welefish method is not working for me)

```
let en = LANG_EN_NAME;
let er = LANG_AR_NAME;
let fr = LANG_FR_NAME;

const dictionary : any = {
    en: LANG_EN_TRANS,
    er: LANG_AR_TRANS,
    fr: LANG_FR_TRANS
};

// providers
export const TRANSLATION_PROVIDERS = [
  { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: dictionary },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, do what the compiler says :). Export your dictionary:

```
export const dictionary : any = {
    [LANG_EN_NAME]: LANG_EN_TRANS,
    [LANG_AR_NAME]: LANG_AR_TRANS,
    [LANG_FR_NAME]: LANG_FR_TRANS
};
```

Comment: first thanks man for your answer @PierreDuc, well error appear

`ngc: Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Expression form not supported (position 15:5 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol dictionary in D:/Mle/.tmp/app/translate/translations.ts, resolving symbol TRANSLATION_PROVIDERS in D:/Mle/.tmp/app/translate/translations.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in D:/Mle/.tmp/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in D:/Mle/.tmp/app/app.module.ts`

Comment: @OscarBout what issue do you have?

Comment: Exactly the same as @PAncho:

I changed the original: https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-language-translation-in-angular-2-part-1    to your solution and got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Declare the type of [LANG_EN_NAME]:

```
export const LANG_EN_NAME : string = 'en';
```

Worked for me.