# angular2 after upgrade Error encountered resolving symbol values statically

Tags: angular, angular-cli

i had upgraded to the latest angular cli and now i get this error:

> Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'dictionary'. Consider exporting the symbol (position 12:7 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol TRANSLATION_PROVIDERS in C:/xampp/htdocs/milesofmusic/src/app/translate/translation.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/xampp/htdocs/milesofmusic/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/xampp/htdocs/milesofmusic/src/app/app.module.ts

the code it refers to is this:

```
// all traslations
const dictionary = {
    [LANG_EN_NAME]: LANG_EN_TRANS,
    [LANG_HE_NAME]: LANG_HE_TRANS,
};

// providers
export const TRANSLATION_PROVIDERS = [
    { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: dictionary },
];
```

and in my app module i import 
import { TRANSLATION_PROVIDERS } from './translate/translation';
and have it in the providers array

how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
const dictionary  = {
    [LANG_EN_NAME]: LANG_EN_TRANS,
    [LANG_FR_NAME]: LANG_FR_TRANS,

};
```

I am also getting the same error, so do one thing: directly write the language value instead of the brackets.

```
const dictionary  = {
    "en-US": LANG_EN_TRANS,
    "fr-FR": LANG_FR_TRANS,
};
```

Enjoy Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

I believe you got this example from an old guide somewhere on the world wide web. As far as I remember, this one is outdated and it's not the appropriate way anymore to handle translations within angular2. I suggest you take a look at the 
[i18n internationalization](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html) cookbook of angular.

Comment: yeah, that was the first thing i tried. but then i get still: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Expression form not supported (position 13:2 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol dictionary in C:/xampp/htdocs/milesofmusic/src/app/translate/translation.ts, resolving symbol TRANSLATION_PROVIDERS in C:/xampp/htdocs/milesofmusic/src/app/translate/translation.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/xampp/htdocs/milesofmusic/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/xampp/htdocs/milesofmusic/src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: thanks for the answer. i will need to convert it to use the built in i18n. but this answer did work for me [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40643715/587579)

Comment: I was looking for that one! I remembered I saw the same question before :) nice find.